# Rails Loop Through Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

A really simple question but I just can't seem to get it working.

There is only one `Property` included below but there could be more than one within `Properties`. How can I iterate through this hash and display just the `Name` of each `Property`?

```
{"GetPropertiesResponse"=>{"Properties"=>{"Property"=>{"Breakfast"=>"IN", "Country"=>"GB", "Currency"=>"GBP", "Id"=>"1834", "Name"=>"Hotel Name"}}}}
```

I've tried this in my view:

```
<% @json['GetPropertiesResponse']['Properties']['Property'].each do |property| %>
  <%= property['Name'] %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting this error:

**no implicit conversion of String into Integer**

Comment: So...are you going to accept an answer? Did they work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying there might be more than one `property` hash then this should work:

```
<% @json['GetPropertiesResponse']['Properties'].each do |property, value| %>
  <%= value['Name'] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried this but the names of the properties are not outputted and I can't understand why? no errors though

Comment: That should be ```value['Name']```, not ```property['Name']``` in that context ```property``` is the key of each hash.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `#each_value` on this hash since you don't appear to be using the keys

```
<% @json['GetPropertiesResponse']['Properties'].each_value do |value| %>
  <%= value['Name'] %>
<% end %>
```

Should work. Note that the second line is `<%= value['Name'] %>` and **not** `<%= property['Name'] %>`

P.S. On a different note, I don't know why you're using the key "Property" inside of your Properties hash. That just seems like a good way to confuse yourself in exactly this way. Your keys within the Properties hash should be something unique to the property they describe. Since each will be a property, the string "Property" doesn't help describe or differentiate.